# JQuery AJAX call throws Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, response, access-control

I'm working on a project where after using `$.ajax` to make a GET request, I receive an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.  However, the GET request is sent to the server and the response is the expected XML string.

Because of the error, the `success` function never fires, so I can't read the XML response, but I can see it in my logs.  The `error` function doesn't reference the response string, nor does the `complete` function.

Is there another way to look at the response regardless of whether or not the AJAX request fails?  Unfortunately I don't have access to the server to modify the origin restriction, but I do own the box.

Comment: No. Access Denied. You'll have to request it using a server ajax proxy or a 3rd party proxy, such as YQL.

Comment: But I am getting the response back. Is it just that the Access-Denied error won't let the browser parse it?

Comment: Correct. Since it's not a same-origin request, you have no way of accessing it with javascript.

Comment: If I'm accessing a local device (it's an Apple TV in this case) is there a way to change my origin so that the request matches the domain?

Comment: No, you would need to do that from the server you are requesting from using proper CORS headers.

Answer (score 0):

On the response of the server you have to set:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Be carefull because with the '*' the server will be able to respond to everyone without checking the crossdomain restriction. If you want you can put the domain that you make the request.

If you use php:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```